# Coloring Excel rows

Tags: excel, vba

So i found this script on this site to color rows with the same cell-data and change the color when the celldata changes and it seems to work just fine, but i have two minor issues

1. It seems to only apply to the first 900 rows (I have an excel list with 8000+ rows)
2. It colors the entire row, is there a way to make it only color a certain part of the row?

Thanks in advance! here's the script:

```
Public Sub HighLightRows()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2 'start at 2, cause there's nothing to compare the first row with
Dim c As Integer
c = 2       'Color 1. Check http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm for color indexes

Do While (Cells(i, 1) <> "")
    If (Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1)) Then 'check for different value in cell A (index=1)
        If c = 2 Then
            c = 37   'color 2
        Else
            c = 2   'color 1
        End If

    End If

    Rows(Trim(Str(i)) + ":" + Trim(Str(i))).Interior.ColorIndex = c

        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: in terms of point 1, is row 901 blank? If so the while loop will break. I would use a for loop, indicating the last row as activesheet.range("A1000000").end(xlup).row. at this line Rows(Trim(Str(i)) + ":" + Trim(Str(i))).Interior.ColorIndex = c you would need to change it to the range you like activesheet.range("A" & i & ":D" & i) = c

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply! 
I have been trying to add your code to the script but now it mixes up the first collum and places it at the back. 
It is probably my lack of code experience (i'm a script kiddie). 

Is there a way for you to intergrate it for me? 
Basicly what i need is Excel to automaticly color rows that have the same value in ROW A but when the value changes it needs to change the color, these 2 colors can alternate, here's an example (Yellow must stay yellow) : http://i68.tinypic.com/2qjvq5u.png

Comment: Don't use `Integer` for the type of the row index - use `Long`. If you really have over 8000 rows, there is a danger that `Integer` will overflow. In any event, it isn't at all clear why you are even using VBA. Condidtional formatting can do things like this.

Comment: If you have a proper method using Conditional Formatting then i'd be happy to use it! unfortunately i've tried that without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub HighLightRows()

    Const START_ROW As Long = 2 '<< use a Constant for fixed values
    Const VALUE_COL As Long = 1

    Dim rw As Range, emptyCells As Long, i As Long, currentValue, tmp

    Dim arrColors
    arrColors = Array(37, 2)

    Set rw = ActiveSheet.Rows(START_ROW)
    currentValue = Chr(0) 'dummy "current value"

    Do While emptyCells < 10 'quit after 10 consecutive empty cells

        tmp = rw.Cells(VALUE_COL).Value
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
            If tmp <> currentValue Then
                i = i + 1
                currentValue = tmp 'save the new value
            End If
            'assign the color to a specific set of cells in the row
            '   starting at cell 1 and 5 columns wide
            rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = arrColors(i Mod 2)
            emptyCells = 0 'reset empty row counter
        Else
            emptyCells = emptyCells + 1 'increment empty row counter
        End If

        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code only evaluates if the cell is the same as the cell above it. Conditional formatting, as John Coleman said, would be more effective. With it values in the whole column can be evaluated instead of just adjacent ones. And, if I'm not mistaken, there's a setting to look for dup values since Excel 2007, so there doesn't have to be some kind of formula kung-fu to do it.

Unless I'm missing something, it's as simple as Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cell Rules -> Duplicate Values.